# How does Application Level Firewall work?

Tags: macos, firewall, ipfw

I'm a bit confused about OS X Mountain Lion's Application Level Firewall.

I have enabled ALF (Application Level Firewall) in Settings -> Secuity & Privacy -> Firewall and have some rules for some applications in it and those rules are stored by ALF in `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/com.apple.alf.plist`

But it seems that `ipfw` is disabled (no /etc/ipfilter) and `sudo ipfw list` is `65535 allow ip from any to any`. `pf` is also disabled.

So I do not understand how ALF works. If ALF does not use the known legacy firewall applications, how does it do what it does? What does it use for a backend or is it a totally separate application that does not deal with `ipfw` or `pf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ALF uses a process called Firewall. The rules list you are looking for exists under: `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/com.apple.alf.plist`

Additionally, any changes made on a per user basis, is made to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist`.

If you navigate to `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/`, you will also see the Firewall and socketfilterfw processes, which supply the backend and configuration manager (respectively) for ALF.

You can read more about Apple's in-house firewall here: http://krypted.com/tag/socketfilterfw/

Answer (score 1):

See [OS X Server: About the Firewall service](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5413).

Although the topic is about OS X Server, the last paragraph says:

> **Additional Information**
>       The `ipfw` command is deprecated in Mountain Lion. If you want to manually configure Firewall rules, use the `pfctl` binary for forward compatibility. For instructions, see `man pfctl`.

Comment: Thanks, I've already read this article. I know that ipfw is deprecated, but there is no evidence that ipfw or pfctl is used by Application Firewall. So I want to know how actually ALF is working.